# django form got multiple values for keyword argument

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-urls

I have a simple model as follows:

```
RATING_CHOICES = zip(range(1, 6), range(1, 6))
class Rating(models.Model):

    value = models.IntegerField(choices=RATING_CHOICES)
    additional_note = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    from_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='from_user')
    to_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='to_user')
    shared_object = models.ForeignKey(ObjectDetail, null=True, blank=True)
    dtobject = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

From the above model I generate a model form, in my forms.py as follows:

```
class RatingForm(ModelForm):

     class Meta:
          model = Rating
          exclude = ('from_user', 'dtobject',
                     'shared_object')
```

In my urls I try the following:

```
url(r'^rate/(?P<form_type>[\w]+)/(?P<oid>\d+)/(?P<oslug>[\w-]+)/$', 'rating_form', name='rating_form'),
```

And in my views, the following:

```
def rating_form(form_type = None, oid = None, oslug=None):

    print form_type
    form = RatingForm(data=request.POST or None)

    if request.POST and form.is_valid():
           form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
    else:
        return render(request, "share.html", {'form' : form })
```

Doing this gives me the following error:

**rating_form() got multiple values for keyword argument 'form_type'**

Additional Details:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/rate/lending/3/random-stuff/
Django Version: 1.4.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
rating_form() got multiple values for keyword argument 'form_type'
Exception Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py in _wrapped_view, line 20
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 162, accepted):

the first argument to your view should be `request`